# I encountered a strange MySQL connection timeout problem

Tags: mysql

In my Spring Boot project, the exception information is as follows：

```
2023-07-17 10:36:04,587  WARN 537194 --- [         task-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : SpringBootHikariCP - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7554cfe9 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,012 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8,014 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:643)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at xxxxxx.custom.report.service.impl.report.CustomReportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1.exportFile(<generated>)
    at xxxxxx.service.listener.CustomReportEventListener.onApplicationEvent(CustomReportEventListener.java:43)
    at xxxxxx.service.listener.CustomReportEventListener.onApplicationEvent(CustomReportEventListener.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,012 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8,014 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor102.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:581)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:761)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:700)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:1051)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:997)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:575)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
2023-07-17 10:36:04,588 ERROR 537195 --- [         task-9] c.d.q.s.l.CustomReportEventListener      : CustomReportEventListener fail ,errmsg：{}
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:647)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at xxxxxx.custom.report.service.impl.report.CustomReportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1.exportFile(<generated>)
    at xxxxxx.service.listener.CustomReportEventListener.onApplicationEvent(CustomReportEventListener.java:43)
    at xxxxxx.service.listener.CustomReportEventListener.onApplicationEvent(CustomReportEventListener.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:643)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,012 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8,014 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,012 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8,014 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor102.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:581)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:761)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:700)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:1051)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:997)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:575)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

My MySQL database has the following settings:

```
wait_timeout = 5
```

The simplified code is as follows：

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomReportEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomReportEvent> {
    @Autowired
    private ICustomReportService customReportService;
    private static final String LOCK = "LOCK";
    @Override
    @Async
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomReportEvent event) {
        try {
                customReportService.exportFile();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("CustomReportEventListener fail ,errmsg：{}", e); // The exception is caught at this place
        }
    }
}
```

```
public interface ICustomReportService extends IOperations<CustomReportEntity> {
    String exportFile();
}
```

```
@Repository
@Slf4j
public class CustomReportService extends AbstractService<CustomReportEntity> implements ICustomReportService {
    @Override
    public String exportFile() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return "zipPath";
    }
}
```

The stack information obtained at the place where the exception is thrown is as follows：

[image: stack information obtained at the place where the exception is thrown]

There is no @Transactional annotation in the context of my code，and use aspects to understand the start of the transaction.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TransactionAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void beforeTransaction(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Starting transaction for method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @After("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void afterTransaction(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Ending transaction for method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

I found that before the exportFile method is called, all the transactions that have been opened are closed, and no transaction is opened in the exportFile method. This confuses me a lot, I don't know how the problem arises.

Comment: Eh? You have `wait_timeout=5` and `Thread.sleep(8000)` and you're wondering why you get timeouts?

Comment: No, my configuration is to be able to generate timeout exceptions. However, there is no operation of connecting to the database in my code. I am wondering why the exception of CommunicationsException can be caught.Also, from the stack, I can't find the root cause of this exception

Comment: So what is the relevance of the method with the sleep? Was it called before you tried the transaction? If not, why is it in the question?

Comment: The code in the exportFile method will execute for a long time, and sometimes it will exceed the wait_timeout configuration of mysql, causing problems in my code. The sleep here is just to reproduce this problem. I cannot modify the wait_timeout configuration of mysq, so I Try to find the reason, so use the simplest code to reproduce this problem
In addition, after I used the TransactionAspect class, I found that when the onApplicationEvent and exportFile methods started, no transaction seemed to be started. This is where I wonder

Comment: Go read up on JDBC pool management (and use a MUCH bigger timout and and make sure you've got connection checks)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find the root cause, and modified my code to make the running time shorter than the wait_timeout time, which circumvented this problem